# Difference between numpy.logical_and and &

Tags: numpy, logical-operators

I'm trying to use the `logical_and` of two or more numpy arrays. I know numpy has the function `logical_and()`, but I find the simple operator `&` returns the same results and are potentially easier to use.

For example, consider three numpy arrays a, b, and c.  Is
`np.logical_and(a, np.logical_and(b,c))`
equivalent to 
`a & b & c`?

If they are (more or less) equivalent, what's the advantage of using `logical_and()`?

Comment: From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html bitwise "Computes the bit-wise AND of the underlying binary representation of the integers in the input arrays" only applies to ints and Booleans.  It is not quite the same as np.logical_and except when working with booleans

Answer (score 30):

@user1121588 answered most of this in a comment, but to answer fully...

"Bitwise and" (`&`) behaves much the same as `logical_and` on boolean arrays, but it doesn't convey the intent as well as using `logical_and`, and raises the possibility of getting misleading answers in non-trivial cases (packed or sparse arrays, maybe).

To use logical_and on multiple arrays, do:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([a, b, c])
```

where the argument is a list of as many arrays as you wish to `logical_and` together.  They should all be the same shape.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the bitwise operations (such as `&`, etc.) are significantly faster than the corresponding function (such as `logical_and`) if speed is a concern. For me, it was around a 4x difference.

Answer (score 26):

I have been googling some official confirmation that I can use `&` instead of `logical_and` on NumPy bool arrays, and found one [in the NumPy v1.15 Manual](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#numpy-for-matlab-users-notes):

> If you know you have boolean arguments, you can get away with using
>   NumPy’s bitwise operators, but be careful with parentheses, like this:
>   `z = (x > 1) & (x < 2)`. The absence of NumPy operator forms of
>   `logical_and` and `logical_or` is an unfortunate consequence of Python’s
>   design.

So one can also use `~` for `logical_not` and `|` for `logical_or`.

Comment: `Precedence: NumPy’s & operator is higher precedence than logical operators like < and >; Matlab’s is the reverse.`    Exactly the reference I was looking for. Thanks.