# Combining "True" values in multiple list into a single list, (index sensitve)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's suppose I have two lists:

```
l1 = np.zeros(5,bool)
l2 = np.zeros (5,bool)

l1[3] = True 
l2[1] = True
```

Output:

```
[False False False  True False]
[False  True False False False]
```

And based on these lists I want a single list which has indexes set to true based on the index of Trues (one or more) in a number of lists. All the lists have the same length and the target list must have the same length as well. What could be the pythonic way to do that so that I may get the desired list:

List 3: Desired Output:

```
[False True False  True False]
```

Comment: You just want a boolean OR between the two arrays?

Comment: Basically yes, but at some instances the data type changes to int so I was wondering if there is another way (brute force) to have that.

Comment: How does data type changes to int when you are specifying boolean while declaring the list?

Comment: This was an example, even when I have int it is either 0's or 1's and I just realized that I can use a similar approach. (newbie here) 
Thanks for the support. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I understand is that you want to apply an `or` operator between vectors, this would be the way to develop it:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = np.zeros(5,bool)
l2 = np.zeros (5,bool)

l1[3] = True 
l2[1] = True 

l_full = np.logical_or(l1,l2)
l_full
# array([False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: What might the difference be in numpy's logical or and '|' as in previous answers? I mean essentially they perform the same task , but is one better than the other in any other regard?

Comment: A discussion of this can be seen in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384529/difference-between-numpy-logical-and-and/44787336

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as writing

```
l1 | l2
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @kosciej answered.

```
print(l1 | l2)
```

Comment: indeed, looks veeeery similar, maybe change at least order of lists? :P

Comment: Hahaha I have enclosed the lists in the print method :D